# Pandas how to pass in a column of list type into a groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

I have data such as the following:

| Product | Profile URL | Category 1 | Category 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sneakers | place.com | ['basketball','fashion','hippy'] | ['influencer marketing','PPC'] |

I'm trying to filter to see if a product with the same name has instances with different profile URL's in the data. I got that to work through the following:

```py
joined = (
    joined.groupby(["Product", "Profile URL"])
    .aggregate({"Categories_1": "count"})
    .reset_index()
    .groupby("Product")
    .aggregate({"Profile URL": "count"})
)

joined.loc[joined["Profile URL"] > 1]
```

This returns all the Products with more than 1 profile URL. However, I want to pass category 1 and category 2 through the groupby function to create a dataframe with all prodcts that have more than 1 profile URL and their accompanying categories. However, since the categories are list type, I'm getting the following error when I try this:

```py
joined = (
    joined.groupby(["Product", "Profile URL", "Categories_1"])
    .aggregate({"Categories_1": "count"})
    .reset_index()
    .groupby("Product")
    .aggregate({"Profile URL": "count"})
)
```

This gives the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'.

How do I pass the category columns through to keep them?

Comment: You can transform `Categories_1` to `tuple` then do the groupby: `joined['Categories_1'] = joined['Categories_1'].transform(tuple)`

Comment: Yep - [pandas.Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html#pandas.Index) objects (and therefore any grouped columns) cannot have lists, as these are mutable objects and therefore cannot form a stable index. Index elements must be hashable. Convert to tuple as @PanwenWang mentioned.